# Partitioning vectors in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have some values in a vector and wants to partition them (perhaps using divide and conquer method). For example I want to have this function:

```
 vector<vector<int>> SplitVector(vector<int> vectorIn);
```

Assuming **vectorIn** contains these values: **{5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 25, 40};**

The function should do the following: 
1. Compute the average e.g 21 
2. Partition the vector into 2 i.e:
vector A = {5, 10, 15, 20} //values less than the average 
vector B = {25, 25, 30, 40} // values greater than average 
3. Repeat the same thing for both vectors until we are left with partitions with 2 or 1 vectors.

The output for this example will be:

vector A1 :{5, 10}; 
vector A2 :{15, 20}; 
vector B1 : {25, 25}; 
vector B2 : {30}; 
vector B3 : {40};

My code is as below: //First and Second are temp vectors of int

```
 vector<vector<int>> SplitVector(vector<int> vectorIn){
      int AVG = (int) std::accumulate(Input.begin(), vectorIn.end(), 0) / vectorIn.size();
      for(int i = 0; i <vectorIn.size(); i++){
           if(vectorIn.at(i) <= AVG){
                First.push_back(vectorIn.at(i));
           }else{
                Second.push_back(vectorIn.at(i));
           }
      }

      if(First.size() > 2){
           SplitVector(First); //use recursion if we have more than 2 element in vector
      }else{
           Result.push_back(First);
      }
      if(Second.size() > 3){
           SplitVector(First);
      }else{
           Result.push_back(Second);


      return Result;
 }
```

I'm programming in c++. I tried using divided and conquer algorithm but no luck yet. My variables gets re-initialize when the function is called after the first time. Also, i should be able to dynamically create vectors to store the result.  Any help or ideas on how to implement this would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are going to be asked to show the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the method you defined ( may not be the best way as you are passing vectors in recursion , for small inputs no affect on efficiency will be there). Here is kind of a pseudo code

```
  vector<vector<int>> SplitVector(vector<int> vectorIn)
  {
       vector< vector<int> >left,right,result;
       vector<int>l,r;
       if(vectorIn.size() <= 2)
       {
            result.push_back(vectorIn);
            return result;
       }
       double average = 0;
       for(int i = 0;i < vectorIn.size();i++)
           average += vectorIn[i];
       average = average/(vectorIn.size());
       for(int i = 0;i < vectorIn.size();i++)
       {
           double num = (double)(vectorIn[i]*1.0);
           if(num > average)
               r.push_back(vectorIn[i]);
           else
               l.push_back(vectorIn[i]);
       }
       left = SplitVector(l);
       right = SplitVector(r);
       for(int i = 0;i < left.size();i++)
           result.push_back(left[i]);
       for(int i = 0;i < right.size();i++)
           result.push_back(right[i]);
       return result;
  }
```

Having said this you can also do this with arrays with instead of passing arrays passing only indices.